# How to block ubuntu server outbond to a specific ip

Tags: 16.04, firewall, ufw

I'm stting up a ubuntu sever , i need to accept requests from anywhere (0.0.0.0/0) but server need to process only requests to specific ip. ie,nee to restrict outbound ip to one orr two, how would i do it with UFW,

Answer (score 0):

Just type in a Terminal:

```
sudo iptables -I OUTPUT 1 -d 192.168.155.66 -j DROP
```

192.168.155.66 is an example ip. just use your required destination ip address (the one you need to block as a destination).
if you do a list you should see in the Chain "OUTPUT" this:

```
sudo iptables -L -n
...
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.155.66
```

Comment: I tried the above one now i'm not able to ping to my ip from server but can ping all other sites, i need to block my outbound only to a specific ip,

Comment: can you please state the destination outbound ip to block and post a "sudo iptables -L -n" please ?